# Get info about a line using Win2d C#

Tags: c#, uwp, draw, win2d

I'm drawing a line with win2d and C# uwp. I would like to get infomation about that line such as the line length and even a list of points that are used to create that line.  I've tried everything I know and I just can't figure out a solution. Maybe I'm approaching this from the wrong angle? Can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have information about the start and end, can't you apply this?
Length = (y1 - y2)^2 + (x1 - x2)^2

Comment: Yes, I found this: http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/geometry-plane/distance-two-points.php

But I'm still lost on how to get the path of the line in X Y coordinates... still working on it though

Comment: What do you mean by the path? As in the equation of the straight line?